# C# Adding Visible Nodes to Node Array

Tags: c#, arrays, tree, addition

I'm trying to create a function that will add each visible node in a tree to a node array and then return it.

This is the code I have so far, but struggling to figure out how to add them.

Note: The tree has a maximum of 8 nodes.

```
    private Node[] activeClients(AdvTree tree)
    {
        Node[] activeClients = new Node[8];

        foreach (Node client in tree.Nodes)
        {
            if (client.IsVisible)
            {
                //Add Visible Node to activeClients Node Array
            }
        }

        return activeClients;
    }
```

Comment: Does activeClients.Add(client) not work?

Comment: There is no Add definition I checked.

Comment: A wait, too early. In array you set it using an index. For example activeClients[0] = client. Better would be using a List<Node> and use append to add the clients to it. So you don't have to use indexes and range checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like:

```
var visibleNodes = tree.Nodes.Where(client=>client.IsVisible)
```

especially if you are talking about small numbers (8 elements) and not compute intensive function, dynamic array (or vector) like `List<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` is a right choice.

And in this way, your code also scales better in the future.

Comment: If you absolutely need an array, then you could add `ToArray()` afterwards too :-)

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out I didn't need a Node Array, but thanks for the help guys.

I used NodeCollection instead and it worked perfect for my needs.

```
    private NodeCollection activeClients(AdvTree tree)
    {
        NodeCollection activeClients = new NodeCollection();

        foreach (Node client in tree.Nodes)
        {
            if (client.IsVisible)
            {
                //Add Visible Node to activeClients Node Array
                activeClients.Add(client, eTreeAction.Code);
            }
        }

        return activeClients;
    }
```